# PHP - ternary for undefined index

Tags: php, conditional-operator

I have a PHP error notice:

> Undefined index: inventory_amount

```
$chains[$key] = intval($chain_product['inventory_amount']);
```

Is it possible to fix it in one line like with ternary function and not with:

```
if(!empty($chain_product['inventory_amount'])) {
     $chains[$key] = intval($chain_product['inventory_amount']);
}
```

New with PHP. Thanks

Comment: I would be more interested to know why the inventory_amount was missing to be honest

Comment: And if it is missing, what value should `$chains[$key]` get? Nothing at all? Wouldn't that cause the same problem further down the line?

Comment: Also having a problem understanding why you would make a KEY of an inventory amount! Maybe you need to step back, have a cup of tea, and then work out what actually needs fixing here

Comment: Checking for empty would give the same error I suppose? I think you are looking for "isset": https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.isset.php And yes, you can incorporate it into a ternary operator $var = isset($some) ? TRUE : FALSE;

Comment: Ternaries bring nothing to the table other than being more compact line-wise, but that compactness also makes your code more difficult to read and maintain. I would suggest using your existing `if()` statement, which is perfectly clear as to its intent and function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PHP has ternary operator.

Like this:

```
$variable = ( condition ? true : false );
```

So in your case it like this:

```
$chains[$key] = ( !empty($chain_product['inventory_amount']) ? intval($chain_product['inventory_amount']) : 0 );
```

so if you have inventory_amount empty, it will have 0 assigned as a "fallback".

Comment: *fixed missing )